# how to create a for loop in C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

hey I have my program and I would like to know how to add a for loop or a while loop the array. 
I am very confused on how to add them in my code and how to use them.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main ()
{

  char input_string [100];
  cout << "Please enter an input string: ";     // print Please enter an input string
  cin >> input_string;                          //user will input string

  cout << "This is the input string: "<< input_string<<endl;    //print this is the input string

  int mod_int;
  cout <<"Please enter the modification: ";     // print please enter the modification
  cin >> mod_int;                               //user will enter modification integer

  cout<<"Modification integer used is: "<< mod_int <<endl;  // print modification integer used is


  cout << (char)(input_string[0] + mod_int);    //convert the letter according to the mod int. 

  return 0;
}
```

i am trying to add the whole string that is modified according the the mod_int.
so lets say we have an input_string "hello" with a mod_int of 4 I want it to display "lipps" I could do it by copying the "cout << (char)(input_string[0] + mod_int);" multiple time but i want it to loop.

Comment: Try to edit your question to properly format the code.

Comment: @user5451982 what do you wants to display? a specific character of your `input_string` or the whole `string`?

Comment: So you want to increase/decrease the letters used in the string? In this case, hello + 4 = lipps because alphabetically, h + 4 = l, e + 4 = i, l + 4 = p and o + 4 = s?

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= mod_int; i++)
 {
    cout << (char)(input_string[i] + mod_int);
 }
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work :/ would i be adding this before or after the "cout << (char)(input_string[0] + mod_int)"???

Comment: @tas, note the termination case for the loop does not necessarily match the length of the string. This only works by the grace of C'thulu.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
int len = strlen(input_string);

for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    input_string[i] += mod_int;
}
cout << input_string << endl;
```

It transforms input_string into the desired output, then prints the char array normally. Note the use of [strlen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen).

Answer (score -2):

Start with learning some general programming basics. C++ is a hard language to learn, since you need to learn C first. And to really learn C you must know assembler. Your question shows that not only you don't know the basics, but you try to jump over your head and copycat code you don't understand. Because of that beginners loose 90% of their time trying to learn by copy-pasting in vain.